# Getting average sum through hierarchy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a rails 5 app.
In this app I got two objects/models. Scorecard and Measure.

A scorecard can have many Scorecards (children) using scorecard_id.
A scorecard can also have many Measures. Each measure have a score attribute saved as a float.

This hierarchy can be done in two levels:

```
Scorecard A
-> Scorecard B
   -> Measure A (score 7.5)
   -> Measure B (score 8.0)
```

I want to get the average score from Measure A and B for the Scorecard A object.

If I get the Scorecard B I can easily get the average score from Measure A and B using the below method but I need to get it through the top level object (Scorecard A).

```
def score
   self.measures.sum(:score) / self.measures.count
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through each scorecard and measure, and collect both the total score and the count in order to do the calculation at the very end. A quick and dirty version of this would look like this:

```
def score
    count = 0
    total_score = 0
    scorecards.each do |s|
        (c, t) = s.measure_calc
        count = count + c
        total_score = total_score + t
    end
    (c, t) = measure_calc
    count = count + c
    total_score = total_score + t

    return total_score / count
end

def measure_calc
    count = 0
    total_score = 0
    measures.each do |m|
        count = count + 1
        total_score = total_score + m.score
    end
    return count, total_score
end
```